# How to uninstall manual-installed svn?

Tags: svn, uninstall

Becaues of a weird bug, now I need to uninstall subversion which I previously compiled and re-install it from distribution in the hope to fix the bug.

Below are the types(keywords in file or folder name) of files in /usr/local that I am about to remove. Can anyone tell me if it's ok?

Apr

Neon

Serf

libsvn

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: CentOS linux OS

Comment: Is everything in /usr/local?

Comment: yes they are  under /usr/local

Comment: I find the files in a chunk within the time frame of its install

Comment: I've done that. But the bug persists. So I wonder it might be interfering with my old compiled version...I am not very sure actually where my old version was installed. Makefile prefix is /usr/local